# Spider Identification Illinois

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arachnology

I noticed a really huge, beautiful web on my porch last week, and tonight, I discovered its resident. I'm thinking it's an *Araneus diadematus* (Cross Orbweaver), but I was hoping for some confirmation.

Can anyone confirm this or offer a better suggestion?

[image: Zoomed-in crop]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would agree this is some species in the Araneidae. Do you have a picture of the spider's belly? Or a better picture of the spider's web? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is very likely an araneid (or **Orb-weaver spider**) in the family [Araneidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orb-weaver_spider).

Without further evidence, it's hard to narrow down to a species.

One possibility:

[***Neoscona crucifera***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoscona_crucifera) (**Hentz orbweaver**, **spotted orbweaver** or **barn spider**)

[image]

<sup>Source: [Will Cook 2001](http://www.carolinanature.com/spiders/neosconacrucifera.html)</sup>

[image] [image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoscona_crucifera)</sup>

- *Description*:

  - Relatively variable in color (and sometimes pattern), but is usually rusty-red or golden orange color.

    - [This site](http://entomology.ifas.ufl.edu/creatures/misc/spiders/neoscona.htm) suggests females are reddish-brown to brown and males are lighter brown with the sides of the carapace nearly black.
  - Dorsal abdomen is brown and hairy; abdomen underside = black, with two white spots
  - The epithet *crucifera* refers to the cross-like pattern on their back
  - Legs have alternating light and dark brown bands.
- *Size*: females = 9.5-19 mm long; males = somewhat smaller
- *Web*: very large (up to 0.61 m diameter) and often on buildings and other man-made structures
- *Range*: Eastern/Central USA + Mexico

According to [Will Cook](http://www.carolinanature.com/spiders/neosconacrucifera.html),

> Several other species of *Neoscona* are confusingly similar...Other species usually have a bolder pattern.

We can rule out [*Neoscona domiciliorum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoscona_domiciliorum) because Illinois is west of its range and the colroation is different. [[Source](http://entomology.ifas.ufl.edu/creatures/misc/spiders/neoscona.htm)].

Comment: @Dan Do you remember if the spider had dots on the underside of the abdomen?