# Curious on the species of a large Orange Spider?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Heres the images of her:
[image]
[image]
[image]

She just laid a large yellow fuzzy sack of babies recently (Were pretty sure were just going to deposit her and her eggs in a grove in the forest soon)

We have lots of brown recluses here in North Carolina, but no idea what she is.

Climate: Humid, Tropical.

Zone: Sneads Ferry, North Carolina, United States.

Size: About 1.5 Inch, leg spans are about 1 inch on their own.

Comment: Related: [Spider Identification Illinois](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/36929/16866)